# ERROR WHILE ENABLING INPUT METHOD IN ANDROID 14 - ANDROID

Tags: android, kotlin, sdk, securityexception

In Android Enabling input was working fine before but when I tested in Android 14 (sdk 34), I'm getting following exception.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.SecurityException: Settings key: <enabled_input_methods> is only readable to apps with targetSdkVersion lower than or equal to: 33 at android.provider.Settings$NameValueCache.getStringForUser(Settings.java:3547) at android.provider.Settings$Secure.getStringForUser(Settings.java:9482) at android.provider.Settings$Secure.getString(Settings.java:9448)
```

Need help

Answer (score 1):

**According to android official documentation:**

> List of input methods that are currently enabled. This is a string
> containing the IDs of all enabled input methods, each ID separated by
> ':'. Format like "ime0;subtype0;subtype1;subtype2:ime1:ime2;subtype0"
> where imeId is ComponentName and subtype is int32.
>
> Note: This setting is not readable to the app targeting API level 34
> or higher. use InputMethodManager.getEnabledInputMethodList() instead.
>
> Constant Value: "enabled_input_methods"

Here is the [Link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure#ENABLED_INPUT_METHODS) of official docs.